# Can an android device be recognised as a printer?

Tags: android, printing, wireless

I wanted to understand how a computer/smartphone/tablet categorises printers under the printers category, i.e, what specific hardware and/or software on the printers makes this happen? Can an android device be made to be listed under the printers' category somehow?

Comment: Everything is possible! It depends on how you alternate the communication protocol between devices

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen Thanks for the reply, but could you be more specific please? What protocols/hardware do I need to read up on to achieve the aforementioned on an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way you connect to the device/printer. You tagged wireless, but even in that category there are Bluetooth and Wifi. USB is very common way to connect printers. With wifi the device could act as network printer. In practice you need to implement the software for the device to make it look like a printer. Since it is not a printer, the amount of work may be significant and may require rooting the device.

**USB:** usually Android device implements MTP and/or PTP device class. You could implement [printer device class](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/).

**Bluetooth:** Android device implements some file transfer, audio and headset profiles at least. You could implement printer side of [printing profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BPP.aspx).

**Wifi:** you could implement support for [Internet Printing Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol).

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Apologies for not being specific about the wireless part - I am trying to achieve the connection through **wi-fi** only. 
I had already read up on the Internet Printing Protocol, but didn't get a clear picture on what exactly makes devices appear in the "Printers" section to computers and other handhelds. Am I correct in saying that a device listening on port 631 would be seen as a potential "printer" by computers on the same network?

Comment: I think so, but I am not familiar with the details of IPP. I could have told you a bit more about USB though ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it's just wifi I'm concerned with, sir. :) 

Posted a separate, more specific question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841957/how-do-i-open-port-631-on-an-android-device