# How do I open port 631 on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, sockets

What is a sample Android code that could open port 631 on an Android device so that it appears to computers on the same wifi as a potential "printer" device that can thereafter receive data?

I have an Android tablet to experiment with, and so I'm fine with rooting it (if that's what it requires).